# Is it possible to get a list of Dog from a list of Animal without a cast?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, java-7, el

I have a `protected Map<String, List<Animal>> animals;` in my class. In my constructor, I have

```java
animals.put("dogs", new ArrayList<Animal>());
animals.put("cats", new ArrayList<Animal>());
```

and eveything works, as expected. If I want a `Dog` or a `Cat`, I have only to it get from map and cast.

But, what if I should want

```java
animals.put("dogs", new ArrayList<Dog>());
```

`Java` does not allow me this. I read also it in [this SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1763602) But I need it, since I'm using JSF and I need in the EL expression of the page a method of `Dog` that Animal doesn't have.

Since I created a factory for `Animal` I thought to use the factory to get the right object type, but it seems me a little weird.

Is there some way I can use `animals.put("dogs", new ArrayList<Dog>());` or some other alternatives?

PS: I'm using Java 7

Comment: Well, you could use `Map<String, List<? extends Animal>> animals;` which would allow you to do `animals.put("dogs", new ArrayList<Dog>());` but you'd still not be able to get a `ArrayList<Dog>` out of that map without casting. After all, the map could consist other types for other keys so how should the compiler even know what type to return here? You'd need to provide that cast, maybe using specific methods like `List<Dog> getDogs() { return (List)animals.get("dogs"); }` (the raw cast would be necessary so the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: The generics of a map support values of **all the same type**, and you have a map where the values are subtly different types. It sounds like you should be using a `Map<String, List<? extends Animal>>`, but if you want to retrieve your list of dogs as a `List<Dog>`, rather than a `List<? extends Animal>`, you will have to cast it. You can't avoid casting somewhere.

Comment: You probably have incorrectly designed inheritance hierarchy if you have that problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems absurd but the problem was in the JSF code:

```xml
<ui:repeat var="animal" value="#{bean.animals.get('dogs')}" varStatus="status">
```

I don't know why, but changing `var="animal"` to anything else works. I do not need any cast.